# Store results from SQL Queries in a separate pandas data frame with the date of execution

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

I have created a lookup table (in Excel) which has the table and column name for the various tables and the the column names under these table along with all the SQL queries to be run on these fields. Below is an example table.

[image: Lookup Table]

Results from all SQL Queries are in the format Total_Count and Fail_Count. I want to output these results along with all the information in the current version of the lookup table and date of execution into a separate table.

Sample result Table:

[image: Sample_Result Table]

Below is the code I used to get the results together in the same lookup table but have trouble storing the same results in a separate result_set table with separate columns for total and fail counts.

```
df['Results'] = ''
from pandas import DataFrame
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
            cur.execute(row["SQL_Query"]) 
            df.loc[index,'Results'] = (cur.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to load the queries into a `DataFrame` directly using the `read_sql` method: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html.

The one caveat is that you need to use a `sqlAlchemy engine` for the connection. I also find `itertuples` easier to work with.

One you have those your code is merely:

```
df['Results'] = ''
for row in df.itertuples(): 
            df_result = pd.read_sql(row.Sql_Query)
            df.loc[row.Table_Name, 'Total_count'] = df_result.total_count
            df.loc[row.Table_Name, 'Fail_count'] = df_result.fail_count
```

Your main problem above is that you're passing two columns from the result query to one column in `df`. You need to pass each column separately.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I know of sql_engine but not sure how it is more helpful than using pyodbc. Anyhoo, for now this is giving me "Incompatible indexer with Series" error

Comment: At the end of the day, `pyodbc` and `sqlalchemy` are just going to be grabbing data from a database; I just like removing the step of dealing with cursors. Regarding your error, this seems to be the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37815837/python-if-statement-dictionary-incompatible-indexer-with-series

Comment: Got it. I'll use sqlalchemy. 

Error makes sense since the Table column may have the same table name multiple times so they key will be duplicate. Not sure how to get rid of this error

Comment: Do you know how I can do this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59148525/return-multiple-datasets-from-a-stored-procedure#59148525